# How to pass method parameter into method's attribute value?

Tags: c#, security, reflection, attributes, claims-based-identity

I have a method which is decorated with ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute like this:

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, 
                           Resource = "User", 
                           Operation = "accountId")]
IList<Transaction> ViewTransaction(int accountId)
{
     // some code
}
```

Is there anyway to pass the **accoutId parameter** of *ViewTransaction* to *ClaimsPrincipalPermission Operation*?

What I want is to use the *accountId* and then implement custom logic inside ClaimsAuthorizationManager.

Comment: If accountId is being passed as a parameter into your ViewTransaction method (which means that accountId has to exist somewhere else), why can't it be passed in the same way into your attribute?

Comment: Because the I call ViewTransaction(accountId). What do you mean "passed the same way"?

Comment: What I meant was that could you not call accountId as a parameter within your attribute, similar to how you do with your ViewTransaction method?

Comment: I'm sorry but are you asking me a question? The accountId of ViewTransaction() is inputted by end-user. And I want to pass it to the attribute before actual code of ViewTransaction is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attributes expect constant values at compile time.  As a result, you cannot pass dynamic values to your attribute and expect it to compile.  You would have to resort on some reflection to get this to do what you'd like it to do.

```
var method = typeof(YourClassType).GetMethod("ViewTransaction");
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ClaimsPrincipalPermission)) as ClaimsPrincipalPermission;
attribute.AccountId = 1234;
```

You would need to expose another property for your attribute, namely AccountId.
There are obviously some concerns around this type of approach and should be weighed heavily before doing this.  Make sure that you HAVE to have this type of information passed to your attribute.

Alternatively, if your method lives inside of an MVC controller, you can access the value provider from your filter context as explained in this answer.

[ASP MVC C#: Is it possible to pass dynamic values into an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798516/asp-mvc-c-is-it-possible-to-pass-dynamic-values-into-an-attribute)

Comment: I can see that if I try this way, I have to call ViewTransaction in SomeMethod() that has above code. This is not what I want to do. So I thinnk there is no option for this, right?

Comment: No, there is no other way to really do what you are trying to do.  It sounds like you may need to look into subclassing this functionality instead of placing it in an attribute.