# How can i do Authorization based on method parameters against current user claims

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity

Folks,

My goal is to implement some security / checks around what an identity can do and on what resources. Essentially something as shown in the below pseudo code. 
//Assuming entity.Name is the primary key & is stored in the Claims Principal.

My limitations are what comes with ClaimsPrincipalPermissions Attribute.

```
[CheckPermission(CurrentUser.Identity.Name == name)
public BankAccount GetByUser(string name)
{

}

[CheckPermission(CurrentUser.Identity.Name == entity.Name]
public void Update(User entity)
{

}
```

I have refereed various articles around:
the closest: [How to pass method parameter into method's attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925245/how-to-pass-method-parameter-into-methods-attribute-value)
http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/26/using-claims-based-authorization-in-mvc-and-web-api/

I am afraid, i feel that i am missing something obvious here. or is it not?

What is the best practice to implement such a check??