# How can I read method parameter information (names and values) from an attribute class in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

I'm building a cool custom HttpClient wrapper that will using Attributes to build dynamic routes etc. I'm having a problem figuring out how to access the method parameter values from the attribute of the method. Here is an example of a method with my custom Attribute:

```
[RestEndpoint("appointment/{appointmentId}")]
public AppointmentDto GetAppointmentById(int appointmentId)
{
    //code calls base class methods to hit the endpoint defined in this method's attribute 
}
```

Below is my attribute class. In my attribute class, I want to read the parameters of the method it is attached to and in the GetDynamicEndpoint() method, build the Uri doing some replace and regex sugar.

I can't seem to figure out how to actually get the method information that a given Attribute is attached to. I can do the opposite (read attribute info from the method).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RestEndpoint : Attribute
{
    public HttpVerb Verb { get; set; }

    public string Uri { get; set; }

    public RestEndpoint(string uri)
    {
        Verb = HttpVerb.Get;
        Uri = uri;
    }

    public RestEndpoint(HttpVerb verb, string uri)
    {
        Verb = verb;
        Uri = uri;
    }

    public string GetDynamicEndpoint()
    {
        //get method for this attribute and read it's parameters
        //in order to build dynamic endpoint based on method's parameter values          

        return "dynamic endpoint";
    }

}
```

Comment: are you looking for something like the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798516/asp-mvc-c-is-it-possible-to-pass-dynamic-values-into-an-attribute

Comment: What do you mean by "get method for this attribute and read it's parameters"? Attributes with methods have many-to-many relationship, and ,taking into account that they represent static unchangeable properties of code units, they are completely disconnected from method(class) they are applied to. But, if I understand you right, you can get the attribute instance for the method and use its routine with appropriate parameters: `public string GetDynamicEndpoint(IData data)`.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes, but obviously I don't have the luxury of a filter context or a Controller's values provider.

Comment: can this be done via Reflection..?

Comment: @EugenePodskal what I want is the method instance of an attribute. Meaning the context of the called method and it's unique set of parameter values. Since the custom attribute I'm using is applied at method-level, this should be possible without having to pass in a parameter.

Comment: @Britton I mean get the attribute instance inside the method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx and use its[attribute] method to do the needed processing. If you want something less coupled, then you will have to either use some clever trick or take look at [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://www.google.com/?#q=c%23+aspect+oriented+programming)

Comment: Are you asking if you can use reflection to get the values of the parameters that a method was called with?  If so, the answer is that you can't.  Attributes are just metadata associated with the definition of a method, not with its call sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the comments and research, what I am trying to do here is impossible with current built-in .Net framework capabilities. However, I did take @Eugene's advice and passed in the parameters from the method to the attribute to build the dynamic route. Ended-up something like this:

```
[UseRestEndpoint("appointment/{first}/{last}")]
public AppointmentDto GetAppointmentById(string first, string last)
{
    return Send<AppointmentDto>(new { first, last });
}
```

And the Attribute call that builds the dynamic route uri from the passed in dynamic object:

```
public string GetDynamicEndpoint(dynamic parameters)
{
    if (!Uri.Contains("{") && !Uri.Contains("}"))
        return Uri;

    var valueDictionary = GetUriParameterValueDictionary(parameters);

    string newUri = Uri;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in valueDictionary)
        newUri = newUri.Replace(string.Format("{{{0}}}", pair.Key), pair.Value);

    return newUri;
}

private Dictionary<string, string> GetUriParameterValueDictionary(object parameters)
{
    var propBag = parameters.ToPropertyDictionary();
    return GetUriParameters().ToDictionary(s => s, s => propBag[s]);
}


private IEnumerable<string> GetUriParameters()
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<={)\w*(?=})");
    var matchCollection = regex.Matches(Uri);

    return (from Match m in matchCollection select m.Value).ToList();
}
```

This isn't all the implementation code for this to work, but it is what ended up getting the concept to work. Thanks everyone for the comments.